# How to manage dual-sync when single table data is saved to multiples tables from staging table in F&O?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations, power-platform

We don't have rights to make any changes in Finance and Operations (F&O),
Is it possible to manipulate the data of tables??

Scenario :-
we have to sync the dataverse table with F&O where we have line table. It's data is divided into three tables i.e. line table, transaction table and line week. We have setup the mapping of Lines and transaction table but unable to map for the Lineweek table as it is not showing in F&O.

Please help me regarding this

I tried to map Line and transaction table and run these tables simultaneously but there are some field in which data is not populated.